# How to retrieve preparation run list with Shippingbo API?

Tags: api

We need to retrieve preparation run list.

In the documentation, there is a way to get a specific preparation run with a specific id throught :
[https://app.shippingbo.com/preparation_runs/{preparation_run_id}/packing_slip_information](https://app.shippingbo.com/preparation_runs/%7Bpreparation_run_id%7D/packing_slip_information)

But i can't find a way to get the full list of preparation run, the call to https://app.shippingbo.com/preparation_runs returning a 500

Is there a way to get them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint is currently not authorized by API, that's why there is a 500 error

What are trying to do ? Monitoring preparation runs ?

Maybe you can add a webhook on `PreparationRun` resource, and check what you want

Comment: That is what i was suspecting. Yes, it's for a kind of monitoring, I've tryied with webhook, but it seems there's no way to get a preparation run automatically if we don't know the id without a human action throught going to backoffice and get the id of the last preparation.

Comment: The webhook will call you API for each new `PreparationRun` created, in the payload you will retrieve the `id` of the object, then you can call `https://app.shippingbo.com/preparation_runs/{preparation_run_id}/packing_slip_information` with the `id` (instead of preparation_run_id)

Comment: But we can try to allow the route in our side

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer, i gonna try with the webhook later but allowing the route would be easier and great :)

Comment: It is gonna be allowed today or tomorrow

Comment: Ok, will check frequently

Comment: It should be ok now

Comment: I confirm, it' perfect, thanks a lot...